# Session sends user object weirdly

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-9, laravel-session

I'm working on Laravel 9 and I have notices something that I've never seen before.

Basically I'm trying to make a Login system with Laravel 9 and for the next step of logging users in, I added an input to check for the *user mobile phone number*:

```
<input type="text" name="userinput" class="form-control" id="phone">
```

And at the Controller:

```
$findUser = User::where('usr_mobile_phone',$request->userinput)->first();

if($findUser){
         Session::put('userData',$findUser);
         return redirect()->route('auth.login.next');
  }else{
         return redirect()->back()->withErrors('No results!');
  }
```

So as you can see I have send the `userData` object information to the Session called `userData`.

And then for the next Controller method that repsonses to `auth.login.next` route, I added this:

```
public function loginNext()
    {
        $user = Session::get('userData');
        if(Session::has('nextStep') && Session::get('nextStep') == 1){
            return view('frontend.auth.next', compact('user'));
        }else{
            abort(404);
        }
    }
```

Now here, I tried inserting all the object of user to `$user` variable.

So that in the `next.blade.php`, I can check informations like this:

```
@if(!empty($user->usr_password_hash))
// Show button login with password
@endif
```

So it work nice and clean but there is only one problem:

**If I stay at the same page and update the record of returned `$user` manually in the *phpmyadmin* and set the `usr_password_hash` to *NULL***

So the record will be looked like:

[image]

Now the button must not be appeared on the page because this password field is empty. However **it is still showing!**

So this means that session has sent the user object for only one time and this user object is not prototyping live of the user data from the DB.

However if I `dd($user)` at the Controller method, I can properly get the user information:

[image]

So what's going wrong here?

Comment: you are storing an object in the session, that object has no direct relation to anything in the database at this point its just a PHP object ... you would have to retrieve that user from the database every single time if you want it to have the current data

Comment: did you try using `$user->fresh()->usr_password_hash` ?